# Checksum Failed in payumoney in Django?

Tags: django, payment-gateway, payumoney

I have implemented according to docs https://developer.payumoney.com/redirect/

But i am getting error checksum failed, I am using sandbox test url
[image]

view.py

```
import hashlib
from random import randint

from django.shortcuts import render


def Home(request):
    MERCHANT_KEY = "KeytCX7l"
    key = "keytCX7l"
    SALT = "salt2TuHze"
    PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://sandboxsecure.payu.in/_payment"
    posted = {}
    # Merchant Key and Salt provided y the PayU.
    for i in request.POST:
        posted[i] = request.POST[i]
    hash_object = hashlib.sha256(str(randint(0,20)).encode('utf-8'))
    txnid = hash_object.hexdigest()[0:20]
    posted['txnid'] = "b17ef6d19c7a5b1ee83b"
    posted['amount'] =  10.00
    posted['firstname'] = "Ravi"
    posted['email'] = "ravibhushan29@gmail.com"
    # posted['phone'] = "70007240543"
    posted["productinfo"] = "new product"
    hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5"
    posted['key'] = key

    hash_string = ''
    hashVarsSeq = hashSequence.split('|')
    for i in hashVarsSeq:
        try:
            hash_string += str(posted[i])
        except Exception:
            hash_string += ''
        hash_string += '|'

    hash_string += SALT
    hashh = hashlib.sha512(hash_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().lower()
    return render(request, 'payment.html', {"posted": posted, "hash": hashh,
                                                    "MERCHANT_KEY": MERCHANT_KEY,
                                                    "txnid": txnid,
                                                    "hash_string": hash_string,
                                                    "action": PAYU_BASE_URL})
```

I have passing value according to docs of payumoney, I have checked hash and hash_sequence as same as:

hashSequence = key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||salt.

payment.html

```
<html>
  <head onload="submitPayuForm()">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var hash = "{{ hashh }}";
    function submitPayuForm() {
      if(hash =='') {
        return;
      }
      var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
      payuForm.submit();
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>PayU Form</h2>
    <br/>
    {% if error %}

      <span style="color:red">Please fill all mandatory fields.</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      {% endif %}

      <form action={{ action }} method="post" name="payuForm">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ MERCHANT_KEY }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="hash_string" value="{{ hash_string }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="{{ hash }}"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="posted" value="{{ posted }}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="{{ txnid }}" />
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Mandatory Parameters</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Amount: </td>
          <td><input name="amount" value="{{ posted.amount }}" /></td>
          <td>First Name: </td>
          <td><input name="firstname" id="firstname" value="{{ posted.firstname|default:'' }}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email: </td>
          <td><input name="email" id="email" value="{{ posted.email|default:'' }}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product Info: </td>
          <td colspan="3"><textarea name="productinfo">{{ posted.productinfo|default:'' }}</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Success URI: </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input name="surl" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Success/" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Failure URI: </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input name="furl" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Failure/" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
             <tr>

     <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

please help to find where i have made mistake

Comment: does error occur for **live** or **test** payu setup

Comment: in test payu setup

Answer (score 0):

For payu test use this credentials

```
def Home(request):
    key = "gtKFFx"
    SALT = "eCwWELxi"
    PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in/_payment'"
```

hope it helps

for more details refer [this](https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/django-payu-payment-gateway-integration-81b8d03b38ae)

Comment: i have posted dummy MERCHANT_KEY,  and key and salt,
according to doc  test url  
https://test.payu.in/_payment is changed to https://sandboxsecure.payu.in/_payment

Comment: user **gtKFFx** as MERCHANT_KEY for payu test

Comment: No , now after change Merchant key and salt , i am getting error

Sorry, Some Problem Occurred

Comment: did any one get the solution still i am getting 'Sorry, Some Problem Occurred.' currently i am using test credentials key = "gtKFFx" SALT = "eCwWELxi"

Answer (score 0):

first of all you  need not to pass any value in the the view, like you are passing to the posted[] fields.
Second make sure you have switched to the testing mode on your payumoney profile. You can use the credentials available in this mode.
lastly make sure when your form renders on you fill all the mandatory details.